# NGINX location block for routes Lumen/Laravel in subdirectory

Tags: laravel, nginx, lumen, nginx-location

I been searching about this but can't really find a good solution,

I have added lumen project on my nginx server inside the directory 
`/usr/share/nginx/html/sms-api`

I'm trying to access the application via server ip using `http://MY_IP_ADDRESS/sms-api/` and it works fine, but when I access any routes from lumen like `http://IP_ADDRESS/sms-api/login` it just returns 404 Page

here's my location block for sms-api directory

```
# sms-api
location ^~ /sms-api {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/sms-api/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @sms-api;
    location ~* \.php {
        try_files $uri =404;            
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html/sms-api/public/index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
location @sms-api {
    rewrite ^sms-api/(.*)$ /sms-api/index.php/$1 last;
}
# sms-api
```

and the whole default server block for this IP where this above location is located

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  IP_ADDRESS;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # sms-api
    location ^~ /sms-api {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/sms-api/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @sms-api;
        location ~* \.php {
            try_files $uri =404;            
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html/sms-api/public/index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
    location @sms-api {
        rewrite ^sms-api/(.*)$ /sms-api/index.php/$1 last;
    }
    # sms-api

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

would appreciate any guidance and help,

Thanks

Comment: what about folders permissions?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The simple fix for me was to put the Lumen routes in with a prefix of /sms-api